# Expressão regular para trocar o par de variáveis no mysql em arquivo PHP

Tags: regex

Qual expressão posso usar para poder trocar os parâmetros da função do MYSQL, exemplo:

```
mysql_query($query,$db);

mysql_query($db,$query);
```

Porque procuro por mysql_query e troco por mysqli_query depois que conseguir fazer essa mudança.

Ou seja, trocar de lugar duas strings que estejam dentro de um parenteses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode inveter os argumentos criando três grupos no final basta formatar a substituição.

A ideia é quebra essa instrução da seguite forma, o primeiro grupo é `mysql_query` o segundo `$query` e o terceiro `$db`. Com os elementos capturados inverta a ordem do segundo com o terceiro e adicione os parenteses.

O primeiro pega a instrução: `(mysql_query)` o segundo a variável com a query (`\$\w+`), que é representando por um cifrão seguido de uma ou mais letras, seguido de uma virgula e de mais uma variável.

Buscar por:

```
(mysql_query)\((\$\w+)\s*,\s*(\$\w+)\)
```

Substituir por:

```
\1\(\3,\2\)
```

Ou ainda:

```
$1\($3,$2\)
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado.